# Working around "Unable to allocate memory" error during for-loop in Arcpy

Tags: arcgis-desktop, loop, memory

I'm running a very long for-loop in Arcpy (with ArcGIS 10.7 on Win10) over several ten thousand files. It runs smoothly until, everytime after about 3000 iterations (3-4h), it crashes with the error message "unable to allocate memory" and I have to restart it which is unnerving. (My code is too long to post here, I mainly project, clip, merge and copy shape- and rasterfiles and calculate some statistics.)
I have 16GB Ram and at no point are more than 8-9GB used, according to the Task Manager. I suspect that, if it is not just a bug, ArcGIS has some kind of internal memory that fills up with every iteration.

My question is therefore: Is there a command, a function or some way to work around this and keep the loop going?

Comment: I always architect my loops to allow "skip" of completed processes (by creating a semaphore file at the completion of processing, and testing for the file before starting). I'll also architect my bulk processing apps to permit 2-3 concurrent worker sessions, each with its own local temporary workspace, and a runtime flag to indicate for the app to indicate which tasks should be attempted (e.g. `--modulus 0,2` and `--modulus 1,2`  or  `--modulus 0,3`, `--modulus 1,3`,...).  Each also takes a `--stop` flag to indicate a filename to test existence of before moving on to the next task.

Comment: Some arcpy functionality/tools have memory leaks that ESRI never seem to fix so I agree with @Vince I often proactively build into code "a where did I get to flag" so restarting you code allows you to skip the stuff you have done.

Comment: Thanks, you two! I will look into that!